# Fraction Field of Non-Archimedean Valuation Ring and Relate the Divisibility to the Comparison of Absolute Value for Elements in this Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, absolute-value

Let $K$ be a field with $|\ \ |$ a non-archimedean absolute value on it. Define the valuation ring of $|\ \ |$ to be $$R:=\{a\in K:|a|\leq 1\}.$$ I want to prove the following two claims:

> 1. $K$ is the fraction field of $R$
> 2. For all $a,b\in R$, $a|b$ if and only if $|b|\leq |a|$.

For the notation of field of fraction, we denote $\frac{s}{t}$ to be an equivalence class in $\text{Frac}(R)$ by the equivalence relation: for all $s,c\in R$ and $t,d\in R\setminus\{0\}$, $$(s,t)\sim (c,d)\iff sd=tc.$$

---

For 1, firstly, $R$ is an integral domain. Indeed, as $K$ is a field, by definition $1_{K}\neq 0_{K}$. If $0\neq x$ is a zero divisor in $R$, then there exists $y\neq 0$ in $R$ such that $xy=0$. But since $x,y\neq 0$, we have $|x|,|y|\neq 0$, so we have a contradiction $0\neq |x|\cdot|y|=|xy|=|0|=0.$

Now, I understand that the reason of why $K=\text{Frac}(R)$ is that for every $a\in K$, it is either $a\in R$ or $a^{-1}\in R$. Hence, I want to construct a field isomorphism as follows. Let $\phi:K\longrightarrow\text{Frac}(R)$ be a map defined by
$$\phi(x):=\left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
   \frac{x}{1},\ \ \text{if}\ \ x\in R\\
   \frac{1}{x^{-1}},\ \ \text{if}\ \ x\notin R.
   \end{array}
\right.$$

This map is well-defined because if $x\notin R$, then $|x|>1$, and thus $x\neq 0$, so $x^{-1}$ exists and $x^{-1}\in R$. But then I have trouble showing that it is a homomorphism.

Let $x,y\in K$. If $x,y\in R$, then $x+y\in R$, and $$\phi(x+y):=\dfrac{x+y}{1}=\dfrac{x}{1}+\dfrac{y}{1}=:\phi(x)+\phi(y).$$ If $x\in R$ but $y\notin R$, then $|x|<|y|$ and thus $|x+y|=\max\{|x|,|y|\}=|y|>1$, which means that $x+y\notin R$, and thus $$\phi(x+y)=\dfrac{1}{(x+y)^{-1}}.$$ On the other hand, $$\phi(x)+\phi(y):=\dfrac{x}{1}+\dfrac{1}{y^{-1}}=\dfrac{xy^{-1}+1}{y^{-1}}.$$ In this case, how could I show that $\phi(x)+\phi(y)=\phi(x+y)$? Let alone we have a possibly more complicated case when $x,y\notin R$. I am starting to believe that the map $\phi$ is not a good one. But I don't know what alternative I can use.

---

For 2. I can prove that $a|b\implies |b|\leq |a|$. This follows from $|n|\leq 1$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (because $|\ \ |$ is non-archimedean) --- if $b=an$ then $|b|=|an|\leq |a|.$

However, I don't know how to prove the converse. I have several attempted to start the proof by using $|b|\leq |a|$, but it turned out hard to get $a|b$. So, I assumed that $a\nmid b$ and tried to prove that $|b|>|a|$. But a weird thing happened. Suppose that $a\nmid b$ and $a<b$, then let's say $b=na+m$ for some $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m<a$. Then, we have $$|b|=|na+m|\leq\max\{|na|,|m|\}\leq \max\{|a|,|m|\}= |a|,$$ so somehow I proved that $a\nmid b\implies |b|\leq |a|$.

What is wrong with my proof here? Thank you so much!

Comment: For 1, in any case you have that $\dfrac{1}{y^{-1}}=\dfrac{y}{1}$ because $(1,y^{-1})$ is equivalent to $(y,1)$.

Comment: Can you please define $a|b$?

Comment: @Chilote $(1/y^{-1})=y/1$ is true only if $y\in R$. You are saying that $y$ is a unit in $R$, which happens if and only if $|y|=1$. But when I assume $y\notin R$, we have $|y|>1$, so $y/1$ may no make sense? because $y\notin R$ after all.

Comment: @Chilote I believe that $a|b$ if there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ such that $b=na$, and by $na$, it means that $$\underbrace{a+a+\cdots+a}_{n\ \text{times}}.$$ But the book doesn't define it explicitly, so I am not sure.

Comment: I see, well, if $x\in R$ and $y\not\in R$ then we have that $xy^{-1}+1=(x+y)y^{-1}\in R$ and $(x+y)^{-1}\in R$ so their product in Frac$(K)$ is well defined: $\dfrac{xy^{-1}+1}{y^{-1}}\cdot\dfrac{(x+y)^{-1}}{1}=\dfrac{1}{1}$. Therefore, $\dfrac{1}{(x+y)^{-1}}=\dfrac{xy^{-1}+1}{y^{-1}}$.

Comment: For 2, I think that makes more sense to define division in $R$ as follows: $a|b$ if and only if $b=ak$ for some $k\in R$. In that way, 2 follows easily.

Comment: @Chilote I am sorry for the late reply. Your proof of 1. is so smart. I am still thinking about the case when $x,y\notin R$, but I believe that I can do it. For 2, yes, your definition makes more sense, and to prove $(\Leftarrow)$, it is indeed immediate, because $|b/a|\leq 1$ and thus $b/a\in R$, which means $b/a=k$ for some $k\in R$, and thus $b=ak$.

Comment: @Chilote wanna post an answer so that people can upvote?? :). You don't need to more detailed than these comments.

Comment: @Chilote sry, by $|b/a|\leq 1$, I mean that $|ba^{-1}|\leq |a|\cdot|a^{-1}|=1,$ and thus $ba^{-1}\in R$.

Comment: I think I won't post an answer. Not enough energy. You could post an answer showing proofs with full details for completion's sake. Also, in that post, you could comment on the relevance of these results. Are they used to prove other results? You could cite the mentioned book as well. Cheers!

Comment: @Chilote No problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Chilote, I am going to answer my own question. I am reading the book "Algebra Volume II: Fields with Structure, Algebras and Advanced Topics" by Falko Lorenz. This is not a widely-used book to learn field theory, but I found it accidentally and it has everything I need --- especially a good illustration of the extension of absolute value to any number field and to any purely inseparable extension field, and a clear introduction of local field theory. The good part of this book is that it doesn't require too many prerequisites.

I never formally learnt the theory about absolute values on fields, so I decided to work through Chapter 23 before going to local field theory.

My question related to Page 45 of this book when he introduced the non-archimedean valuation.

Let $K$ be a field, and let $|\ \ |$ be a non-archimedean absolute value on it. Then, he gave the following proposition:

> 1. $R:=\{a\in K:|a|\leq 1\}$ is a subring of $K$, called the valuation of ring of $K$
> 2. $K$ is the field of fration of $R$
> 3. $\mathfrak{p}:=\{a\in K:|a|<1\}$ is an ideal of $R$, called the valuation ideal of $K$.
> 4. An element $a\in K$ is a unit of $R$ if and only if $|a|=1$. Thus, $R^{\times}=R\setminus\mathfrak{p}$. It then follows that $R$ is a local ring and $\mathfrak{p}$ is its maximal ideal.
> 5. $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field, called the residue field of $K$ with respect to $|\ \ |$.
> 6. For $a,b\in R$, $a|b$ if and only if $|b|\leq|a|$. (As suggested by Chilote, we say that $a|b$ if and only if there exists $k\in R$ such that $b=ak.$)

My questions is 2 and 6. As most of these results are immediate, I will give a full proof of this proposition for future reference if anyone is interested in this.

---

1. $R$ clearly contains the multiplicative identity $1_{K}$ because $|1_{K}|=1$. Let $a,b\in R$, then $|a+b|\leq\max\{|a|,|b|\}\leq 1,$ and thus $a+b\in R$. Since $|-a|=|a|$, $-a\in R$ also holds. Hence, $R$ is an additive subgroup of $K$. Moreover, $|ab|=|a||b|\leq 1$ since both $|a|$ and $|b|$ are at most $1$. Hence, $ab\in R$, and thus $R$ is a subring.

---

2. Firstly, $R$ is an integral domain. Indeed, as $K$ is a field, by definition $1_{K}\neq 0_{K}$. If $0\neq x$ is a zero divisor in $R$, then there exists $y\neq 0$ in $R$ such that $xy=0$. But since $x,y\neq 0$, we have $|x|,|y|\neq 0$, so we have a contradiction $0\neq |x|\cdot|y|=|xy|=|0|=0.$ Hence, it makes sense to consider the field of fraction $\text{Frac}(R)$ of $R$. Let $\phi:K\longrightarrow\text{Frac}(R)$ be a map defined by
   $$\phi(x):=\left\{
      \begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{x}{1},\ \ \text{if}\ \ x\in R\\
      \frac{1}{x^{-1}},\ \ \text{if}\ \ x\notin R.
      \end{array}
   \right.$$

This map is well-defined because if $x\notin R$, then $|x|>1$, and thus $x\neq 0$, so $x^{-1}$ exists and $x^{-1}\in R$.

Let $x,y\in K$. If $x,y\in R$, then the strong triangle inequality implies that $x+y\in R$, and $$\phi(x+y):=\dfrac{x+y}{1}=\dfrac{x}{1}+\dfrac{y}{1}=:\phi(x)+\phi(y).$$

If $x\in R$ but $y\notin R$, then $|x|<|y|$ and thus $|x+y|=\max\{|x|,|y|\}=|y|>1$, which means that $x+y\notin R$, and thus $$\phi(x+y)=\dfrac{1}{(x+y)^{-1}}.$$ On the other hand, $$\phi(x)+\phi(y):=\dfrac{x}{1}+\dfrac{1}{y^{-1}}=\dfrac{xy^{-1}+1}{y^{-1}}.$$ But $$y^{-1}(x+y)=y^{-1}x+1\implies y^{-1}=(x+y)^{-1}(y^{-1}x+1)\implies (1,(x+y)^{-1})=(xy^{-1}+1,y^{-1}),$$ which means that $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y).$ A similar proof can be applied to the case of $x\notin R$ and $y\in R$.

If $x\notin R$ and $y\notin R$, then $$\phi(x)+\phi(y)=\dfrac{1}{x^{-1}}+\dfrac{1}{y^{-1}}=\dfrac{y^{-1}+x^{-1}}{x^{-1}y^{-1}}.$$ If $x+y\notin R$, then $$\phi(x+y)=\dfrac{1}{(x+y)^{-1}}.$$ But
\begin{align*}
x^{-1}y^{-1}(x+y)=y^{-1}+x^{-1}&\implies x^{-1}y^{-1}=(y^{-1}+x^{-1})(x+y)^{-1}\\
&\implies (1,(x+y)^{-1})=(y^{-1}+x^{-1},x^{-1}y^{-1})\\
&\implies \phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y).
\end{align*}
If $x+y\in R$, then $$\phi(x+y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1},$$ but we have seen that $$x^{-1}y^{-1}(x+y)=y^{-1}+x^{-1}$$ and thus $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y).$

Hence, $\phi$ preserves addition. To prove the perseverance of multiplication, let $x,y\in K$, and if $x,y\in R$, then $xy\in R$, and it is clear that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$. If $x,y\notin R$, then $xy\notin R$, and thus once again it is clear that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$.  If $x\in R$ but $y\notin R$, then $$\phi(x)\phi(y)=\dfrac{x}{y^{-1}},$$ but $x=(xy)y^{-1}$ ensures that $\phi(x)\phi(y)=\phi(xy)$ when $xy\in R$, and $(xy)^{-1}x=y^{-1}x^{-1}x=y^{-1}$ ensures that $\phi(x)\phi(y)=\phi(xy)$ when $xy\notin R$.

Finally, $\phi(1):=\dfrac{1}{1}$ which is the identity of $\text{Frac}(R)$, and thus $\phi$ is a field homomorphism.

It is surjective, because for any $\frac{s}{t}\in\text{Frac}(R)$, let $(a,b)$ be a representative of $\frac{s}{t}$. Note that $b\neq 0$ and $b^{-1}\notin R$, so we have $$\phi(ab^{-1})=\phi(a)\phi(b^{-1})=\dfrac{a}{(b^{-1})^{-1}}=\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{s}{t}.$$

It is injective, because for any $x\in K$ such that $\phi(x)=\frac{0}{s}$ for any $s\in R\setminus\{0\}$, then $x\in R$ must hold otherwise $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x^{-1}}=\frac{0}{s}$ implies that $s=0$, contradiction. So $x\in R$, which means that $\phi(x)=\frac{x}{1}=\frac{0}{s}$ implying that $xs=0$, since $s\neq 0$ and $R$ is an integral domain, it implies that $x=0$.

Hence, $\phi$ is a field isomorphism and $K\cong \text{Frac}(R)$.

---

3. Immediate. Closure under addition follows from the strong triangle inequality.

---

4. Let $a\in R$ be a unit in $R$. Then, there exists $b\in R$ such that $ab=1$, and thus $|a|\cdot|b|=1$. If $|a|<1$, then $|b|>1$ must hold, but this is a contradiction because $b\in R$. Hence, $|a|=1$ must hold. Conversely, let $a\in R$ be such that $|a|=1$. Since $a\in K$ and $K$ is a field, it must have a multiplicative inverse $b\in K$ such that $ab=1$ and thus $|a|\cdot|b|=1$. But $|a|=1$, which means that $|b|=1$, and thus $b\in R$, and thus $R$ contains the multiplicative inverse of $a$, and thus $a$ is a unit in $R$.

Hence, $R^{\times}=R\setminus\mathfrak{p}$. It is clear that $\mathfrak{p}\neq (1)$, because $1\notin\mathfrak{p}$. We just prove that every element $x\in R\setminus\mathfrak{p}$ is a unit in $R$, which means that $R$ is a local ring and $\mathfrak{p}$ is its (only) maximal ideal. (Atiyah-MacDonald Proposition 1.6.)

---

5. Immediate because $\mathfrak{p}$ is the maximal ideal of $R$.

---

6. Immediate. If $b=ak$, then since $k\in R$, we have $|b|=|a|\cdot|k|\leq |a|.$ Conversely, if $|b|\leq |a|$, then $|b a^{-1}|\leq |a|\cdot|a^{-1}|=1,$ and thus $ba^{-1}\in R$, and thus there exists some $k\in R$ such that $ba^{-1}=k$, which means that $b=ka$.

---

Please let me know if you find any mistakes. I am really grateful for the help from Chilote!

---

As suggested by reuns, I believe that the following field isomorphism is much easier to deal with: $$\phi_{2}:\text{Frac}(R)\longrightarrow K\ \ \text{defined by}\ \ \dfrac{s}{t}\mapsto st^{-1}.$$

For this map $\phi_{2}$, it is much easier to prove that it preserves the addition, multiplication and  multiplicative identity. It is also easy to show that it is injective. But one needs to verify that $\phi_{2}$ is independent of the choice of the representative of $\frac{s}{t}$.

Indeed, let $(a,b)\in\frac{s}{t}$, then we know that $(a,b)=(s,t)$ which means that $bs=at$ and thus $ab^{-1}=st^{-1}$.

I believe that this works in any case as long as $R$ is a subring of the field $K$. (And I believe that $R$ needs to be an integral domain to make $\phi_{2}$ injective.)

In our special case, this map is surjective. Because for any $a\in K$, if $a\in R$, then $\phi_{2}(a/1)=a\in K$. If $a\notin R$, then $a^{-1}\in R$, and thus $\phi_{2}(1/a^{-1})=a\in K$.

Hence, $K\cong\text{Frac}(R).$

Comment: For 2. $R$ is a subring of $K$ so $Frac(R)$ is a subfield of $K$. If $a\in K$ and $a\not \in R$ then $|a|> 1$ so $a^{-1}\in R$ whence $a\in Frac(R)$ which is the whole of $K$.

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. It is 100% obvious that if $R$ is a subring of a field $K$ then so is $Frac(R)$. The equivalence classes is for non-integral domains, we need to quotient by some kernel before adding the inverses.

Comment: @reuns yes! You are soooo right. So to prove $\text{Frac}(R)$ is a subfield of $K$, we need to find an injective field homomorphism and identity $\text{Frac}(R)$ with a subfield of $K$ via the image. One way to do this is $$\phi_{2}:\text{Frac}(R)\longrightarrow K\ \ \text{defined by}\ \ \dfrac{s}{t}\mapsto st^{-1}.$$ I have added some details in my answer. And you are suggesting a much better map. In our special case, it is surjective. Brilliant!.

Comment: @reuns ah. ok I get it. Indeed I am overcomplicating it.